# iOS build match profile error - phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I face an IOS build issue error message is 
Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching.

Last time i used the ios build was on 11 december 2014. Today when i tried to update the application and press rebuild with the same key i recived the following error . I deleted the key and created again ..but i got the same error. I followed this tutorial over and over again but no succes ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3Y1a... ).

Anyone got the same issue ? How i can resolve it ?

Comment: same problem, nothing works. started hating iOS ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted about this same answer to your question on the PG Build forums, and took to Stack Overflow to see if I could help others.  I found that re-exporting my developer cert (p12 file)  from Keychain Access did the trick!  Can you try that?

Comment: the only thing that is grayed-out is the exact thing I need - this p12 file. Can't export p12. Tried at least 4 different approaches that I got online and nothing worked. Cannot export to p12. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi - This link shows how to export the p12 - have you tried this? http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/how-to-share-an-apple-certificate-and-its-private-key/

Comment: I did. Managed to do it later with i-dont-know-what. It just started working (p12 not grayed, everything else was). probably a different cert export or something. thanks

Comment: Link above from @dotNetKnow is 404

Comment: @evanmcd new link: https://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/article/how-to-share-an-apple-certificate-and-its-private-key/

Answer (score 0):

Open up your keychain access application and look at your certificates. You should see at least one that starts with "iPhone", take a look to see whether the certificate has expired, the certificates that Apple generates are only valid for 1 year.

Comment: expire date : 6 january 2018

Comment: That looks like a new certificate - you probably need to regenerate your deployment profile

Comment: fun fact ..when i've tried with Development Certificate and Development Provisioning Profile it worked to build my app but when i try with Production Certificate and Distribution Provisioning Profile ( like in the video of youtube i've posted ) isn't working ...same error.